# AWS CLI sync from S3 to local fails with Errno 20

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

Im using the following command

```
aws s3 sync s3://mys3bucket/ .
```

to download all the files AND directories from my s3 bucket "mys3bucket" into an empty folder. In this bucket is a directory called "albums". However instead of copying the files into a "albums" directory, I am receiving the following error message (an example)

```
download failed: s3://mys3bucket//albums/albums/5384 to albums/albums/5384 [Errno 20] Not a directory: u'/storage/mys3bucket//albums/albums/5384'
```

When I look in the folder to see what files, if any, did get copied into the albums folder, there is only 1 file in there called "albums" which when I edit it contains the text "{E40327AD-517B-46e8-A6D2-AF51BC263F50}".

This behavior is similar for all the other directories in this bucket. I see more of the error #20 by far than I see successful downloads. There is over 100GB of image files in the albums folder but not a single one is able to download.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to add `--content-type "UTF-8"` to the command

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it still seems to be creating files with the hexadecimal inside of it instead of creating the folders like it should be doing.

Comment: Are you using the latest AWS CLI version? Check with https://github.com/aws/aws-cli

Comment: You are getting `errno.ENOTDIR` and it looks like `subdir` is used over a file and I believe it must be fixed in latest versions.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem here is that you have both a 'directory' and a 'file' on S3 which have the same name. If you delete the 'file' from S3 then you should find that the directory will sync again.

I have found that this situation can occur when using desktop clients to view an S3 bucket, or something like `s3sync`.

http://www.witti.ws/blog/2013/12/03/transitioning-s3sync-aws-cli/